# Finding the number of the day in a week in PHP from a date ( d-m-Y ) format

Tags: php, date, weekday

I have a variable `$date='15-06-2013'` . Now, how do I get the number of the day in the week? 15-06-2013 is a `Saturday` and hence my function should return `6` as the number if I were to use `N` format character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
echo $day_of_week = date('N', strtotime('15-06-2013'));
```

## Output

```
6
```

### Codepad

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class:-

```
echo (new \DateTime('15-06-2013'))->format('N');
```

Output:-

```
6
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/ntHJd)